# JavaFX Borderpane without left and right children

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I wondering if there's a way to make Borderpane have the node set at the center to take up the full width of the window if there are no children in the left and right slots.  I used Scene Builder to create the FXML file and currently, when I resize the window of the application, there are massive white spaces to the left, right, and bottom of the node in the center. Is there a way to get rid of them?

Here is what it currently looks like:

[image]

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a `Node` centered in a [BorderPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/BorderPane.html) it will be resized to fill the remaining space in the center.

> The top and bottom children will be resized to their preferred heights
>   and extend the width of the border pane. The left and right children
>   will be resized to their preferred widths and extend the length
>   between the top and bottom nodes. **And the center node will be resized
>   to fill the available space in the middle.** Any of the positions may be
>   null.

But it gets resized using the layout bounds of the actual `Node`.

If you take a look on the documentation of [maxWidth](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#maxWidth-double-) and [maxHeight](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#maxHeight-double-) methods of `Node`:

> Returns the node's maximum width(height) for use in layout
>   calculations. If the node is resizable, its parent should not resize
>   its width any larger than this value. A value of Double.MAX_VALUE
>   indicates the parent may expand the node's width beyond its preferred
>   without limits.

So, without seeing your actual code I guess the problem is that you have set the maximal size of your control that you have placed into the center of the `BorderPane`, therefore it does not get resized beyond that limit. As the documentation states you should set it to `Double.MAX_VALUE` to make the `BorderPane` able to resize it to fill the whole space left.

Comment: You beautiful human, this fixed my problem exactly. I have been struggling for HOURS. Thank you.