# JavaFX - Issue when including another fxml to a border pane center of a main fxml

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to include an additional fxml in a main fxml, border pane center. When I do this, the fxml gets included and shows in the center, but the fxml does not occupy the full width and height of the main fxml window.

In the SceneBuilder, if I add the TableView in the center of the borderpane, it acts as it should. Only when I include the fxml via code it does not.

Please help, what am I missing? Any help will be appreciated!

This is what I need:
[image]
This is what I get:
[image]
Main FXML:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<TabPane fx:id="TabPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="800.0" prefWidth="1300.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
  <tabs>
      <Tab fx:id="lecturersTab" closable="false" text="Lecturers">
         <content>
            <BorderPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
               <center>
                  <TableView prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
                      <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
                    </columns>
                  </TableView>
               </center>
            </BorderPane>
         </content>
      </Tab>
      <Tab fx:id="membersTab" closable="false" text="Members">
        <content>
            <BorderPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
           <center>
       <fx:include fx:id="memberPage" source="GUImembers.fxml"/>
              </center>
            </BorderPane>
        </content>
      </Tab>
  </tabs>
</TabPane>
```

FXML I want to add:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<BorderPane fx:id="memberPage" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="700.0" prefWidth="1300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="GUImembersController">
   <center>
      <TableView BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C1" />
          <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="C2" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Main:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MainClass extends Application 
{   
public FXMLLoader loader;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    launch(args);
}   

public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception 
{
    loader = new FXMLLoader();      
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("FXML/GUImain.fxml"));
    loader.setController(new GUImainController());

    Parent root = loader.load();                    
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);      

    stage.setTitle("VIA - Event Management System");
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();       
}
}
```

Comment: No one? This is driving my crazy...As far as I know, whatever you put in the center of the border layout, it should take the full width and the height of the container, given that there is nothing in the top, left, right and bottom sections. Why is it not happening this time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after long hours of fighting with java fx, I got the sollution, which was quite simple. Thanks to this question : [JavaFX Borderpane without left and right children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37872241/javafx-borderpane-without-left-and-right-children)